# pointer and struct issue

Tags: c, pointers, struct

function `find_young()` have to receive pointer `p` as an actual parameter.
And `p` have to point a `struct s` which has youngest person.
There is no error message but the program isn't work.
Please give me some advice.

```
typedef struct
{
    char *name;
    int age;
} PERSON;

void find_young(PERSON **ip)
{
    PERSON s[3] = {{"John", 25}, {"Brandon", 28}, {"Alex", 30}};
    int i;
    int min = s[0].age; 
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if(min > s[i].age)
            **ip = s[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    PERSON *p;
    find_young(&p);
    printf("The youngest person is %s.\n", p->name);
}
```

Comment: a advice `PERSON *p;` --> `PERSON p;` also `s[0]` is not set when the minimum.

Comment: can you explain that more easily?

Comment: [Concrete fix example](http://ideone.com/KXQOrG)

Comment: What I should do if I have to use double pointer?

Comment: Your pointer has not been set should pointer  point to the Object(PERSON Object). E.g `PERSON aMan; PERSON *p = &aMan;`

Comment: your s[3] inside find_young is a local array that would be invalidated after the function call. use "static PERSON s[3]" instead. And "**ip = s[i]" should be changed into "*p = &(s[i])" because you should set a pointer instead of copying the value.

Comment: Answer edited. Do take a look.

Comment: [double pointer ver](http://ideone.com/4e5dy8)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a number of changes in your code to make it work

---

1) You need to allocate memory to the `struct`, and for the `char* name` in the struct

```
int main()
{
    PERSON *p = malloc(sizeof(PERSON));
    p->name = malloc(100);
    find_young(&p);
    printf("The youngest person is %s with age %d.\n", p->name, p->age);

    free(p->name);
    free(p);
}
```

---

2) Then you need to copy both the `name` and `age` values to the passed `struct` properly

```
void find_young(PERSON **ip)
{
    PERSON s[3] = {{"John", 25}, {"Brandon", 28}, {"Alex", 30}};
    int i;

    int min = s[0].age;             //copying the first value
    (**ip).age = s[0].age;
    strcpy((**ip).name, s[0].name);

    for(i = 1; i < 3; i++)          //starting from the next values to compare
    {
        if(min > s[i].age)
        {
            (**ip).age = s[i].age;
            strcpy((**ip).name, s[i].name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind you its best practice to include `free()` statements after the printf in the `main()` function. Otherwise if the program doesn't terminate after that you have a memory leak.

Comment: @Magisch, I always miss that. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

- either, for `p`, before passing `&p` to the function
- or, for `*ip`, inside the function

you need to allocate memory. Other wise, you'll end up dereferencing invalid pointer, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).